# Why my code is not compiling?

Tags: c++

I don't understand what is wrong with my code in here. I have created a function called pause() where everything seems okay but the compiler is catching errors.
Another problem is when ever i run the code and select option-1, it goes to option 1 but doesn't do anything else for as there are more codes are written for it.Please run the code given below and let me know. I am using Code blocks.
Pleas help me out. Thank You.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
#define size 550000;

class morsecode{
private:
    string text;
    char msg[10001];

public:

    void choose();
    void convert();
    void translate();
    void exit();

    void pause(int p){
        for(int i=0;i<p;i++){
            for(long int j=0;j<size;j++){

            }
        }
    }

};
void morsecode::choose(){
    system("CLS");
    cout << "1.Convert message\n";
    cout << "2.Translate message\n";
    cout << "3.Exit\n";
    cout << "\nEnter the number you want to choose:";
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    if(a==1){
        convert();
    }
    else if(a==2){
        translate();
    }
    else if(a==3){
        exit();
    }
    else{
        system("CLS");
        cout << "Wrong input\n";
        pause(3);
        choose();
    }
}

void morsecode::convert(){
    system("CLS");
    cout << "Enter the message you want to convert to morse code:\n\n";
    getline(cin,text);
    int len=text.length();
    cout << len;

}

void morsecode::translate(){
;
}
void morsecode::exit(){
;
}



int main(){
    morsecode obj1;
    obj1.choose();



    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you run your code if it is not compiling?

Comment: Compilers don't catch errors. Either there are errors, and the program isn't created, or there are warnings. Please show the warnings first.

Comment: Also: why do you mix `std::cout` and `getline`? There's `std::in` to replace `getline` and `printf` to replace `std::cout` - if you wish to revisit your code next week you'll wish to choose one concept and stick with it.

Answer (score 4):

Your code compiles in XCode except for this line:

```
#define size 550000;
```

change to:

```
#define __size 550000
```

Also, please don't pause like this as it wastes resources:

```
void pause(int p){
        for(int i=0;i<p;i++){
            for(long int j=0;j<size;j++){

            }
        }
    }
```

Rather use `this_thread::sleep_for()` or some other similar method.

Comment: @dromal The worst part about the `pause` code is not that it waist resources. The worst part is that the compiler may optimize the code and remove both loops so that there is no "pause". Your suggestion, i.e. `this_thread::sleep_for()` is the way to go. +1 from here :)

Comment: Also the define for size() caused the compiler to not recognize functions named size() (pretty much most of STL) so perhaps the OP should use const int.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
#define size 550000;
```

Dont put a `;` at the end of the define. Just do:

```
#define size 550000
```

When you have the "extra" `;` this code

```
for(long int j=0;j<size;j++){
```

is turned into

```
for(long int j=0;j<550000;;j++){
                         ^^
```

which is illegal syntax

Answer (score 1):

Can you please run the code and select option one?
I dont know why but the below portion of the code is not working.

```
void morsecode::convert(){

system("CLS");
cout << "Enter the message you want to convert to morse code:\n\n";
getline(cin,text);
int len=text.length();
cout << len;
}
```

Comment: `Not working`... Describe what happens - what goes wrong - what did you expect.